# How to set a controller action similar to 'new' in a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I have a nested resource defined in routes.db:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :transactions do 
end
```

I would like to create a route that is similar to 'new', but the action would be new_transfer, which would allow me to handle a special type of new transaction:

```
new_account_transaction GET    /accounts/:account_id/transactions/new(.:format)      transactions#new
```

I tried to define the resource including a method definition:

```
resources :accounts do
    resources :transactions
    member do 
      get 'new_transfer'
    end
end
```

or

```
resources :accounts do
   resources :transactions do 
      member do 
         get 'new_transfer'
      end      
   end
end
```

but I get:

```
new_transfer_account GET    /accounts/:id/new_transfer(.:format)                  accounts#new_transfer
```

or

```
new_transfer_account_transaction GET    /accounts/:account_id/transactions/:id/new_transfer(.:format) transactions#new_transfer
```

The second one is close, but I think it really should be transactions/new_transfer.  If this is the best I can do, I then could not find the path that would satisfy to create a new link.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also tried adding a specific match.  What would be the link_to for this route?

```
match '/accounts/:account_id/transactions/new_transfer', to: 'transactions#new_transfer'

/accounts/:account_id/transactions/new_transfer(.:format) transactions#new_transfer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the match method for the routes?

Their example [on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
match "/patients/:id" => "patients#show"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually I tried this as well. I could still not figure out what link_to path would be. Will edit original post with what I tried.